# How do you create an mnesia schema in a specified directory from Application.start callback in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, mnesia

So I have a Phoenix 1.3 application. I read that you have to create an mnesia schema before your application starts up so you can then create an application table.

In config.exs, I have:

```
config :mnesia, 'path/to/mnesia/#{node()}'
```

In application.ex:

```
defmodule MyApp do
  use Application

  def start(_, _args) do
        :mnesia.stop()
        :mnesia.create_schema([node() | Node.list()])
        :mnesia.start()
  end
end
```

Now, Mnesia.nonode@nohost gets created in the topmost level directory of my application if I comment out the line in config.exs. But if I do try and specify a directory in config.exs, I see a message like `{:aborted, {:bad_type, :region, :disc_copies, :nonode@nohost}}`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `config` is a *compile-time* beast, one cannot expect `node()` to be retrieved in the runtime. It’s compiled and hard-coded to what `node()` returns in *compile-time*.

That said if you compile your application on node `foo`, the config in runtime is hardcoded to `'path/to/mnesia/foo'` on *all nodes*. (It seems—according to the error you receive back—the compilation happens at `:nonode@nohost`.)

To fix this, you should store the prefix of the path in the `config` and configure `mnesia` in runtime on each node by appending `'#{node()}'` to the prefix.